# No login screen, unable to login on tty2 to tty6 with "Login Incorrect" error

Tags: nologin

I'm getting this problem after my computer froze while updating. I use Fedora 28 KDE. I was shown in task bar that there 171 updates, so I clicked it, as it was updating the computer froze, so I pressed the reset button, since then I'm getting this problem.

I don't see any login screen, but I see a cursor over black screen, I can move this cursor. Hoping to login through command line, when I pressed `CTRL+ALT+F2-F6`, the text login, shows `"Login Incorrect"` when I type in my username and press `"ENTER"` to proceed to typing password. This problem exists across all Fedora entries on GRUB2 menu.

When I removed `"rhgb"` from one of the GRUB2 Fedora entries and started it, I was shown a real time log of the boot up process, in it I saw these, which I think might be the cause of this problem:

> "ostree-system-generator failed with exit status 127"

and this error below it:

> "Failed to start Security Auditing Service"

Comment: Seems like you got corrupted credential files, most probably /etc/passwd.  Hopefully you may have a system backup that may help you to recover.  This will require some investigation on what files got corrupted.  I suggest you to boot in single user mode (add `single` to the end of your default fedora entry kernel command line).  Once booted you will get a root prompt where you can remount your system as readonly ( `mount -o remount,ro /` ); then you can run fsck as the first step.  This is not an answer, just some thoughts on how to start your system recovery.

Comment: Alternatively, if this is easy for you to remove your harddisk, you can use a USB/SATA adapter to use another system to run the fsck tool.  Good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcelo. You have no idea how appreciative I am for your helpful comments because I've been asking this question at two places officially related to Fedora, but till now I didn't get a reply there. Unfortunately I don't have any backup but I'll try that single user mode and see. BTW sorry I forgot to mention this, mine is an encrypted LVM, I tried mounting and running fsck through Kali which I have on the same hard disk, but because of encryption I had a lot of trouble accessing it, when I managed to get it running(which I'm not even sure I did correctly), the results were clean.

Comment: Instead of Kali (which is used for penetration testing), I recommend [SystemRescuceCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Installing-SystemRescueCd-on-a-USB-stick/) on a USB stick to repair stuff.

Comment: I haven't yet tried the SystemRescueCD but in case it fsck shows clean, what can I do to repair the problem? Is there way I can remove the corrupted credential files and create ones?

Comment: So running fsck from SystemRescueCD also showed clean. What else can I do?